# Why WordPress Core Functions Not Using function_exists()?

Tags: core

This might be a stupid question. But I thought to ask it here.

It is really bad changing core file and I know that there are **actions and filters** in WordPress. But there are some limitations.

So why WordPress Core Functions Not Using function_exists()? I mean something like below example in core files.

```
if(!function_exists('wp_insert_post')){
    function wp_insert_post( $postarr, $wp_error = false ) {

        //Core Code

    }
}
```

Then give a way to run PHP file before core files. So any developer can modify the core files without changing core files.

Comment: Are you trying to modify a certain core behavior?

Comment: @birgire No, I just asked it because I was wondering to know why WordPress team does not allow that feature and I got a answer from Rarst. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Some* do, a number of core functions is specifically designated *pluggable* and contained in [`pluggable.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php) for exactly this purpose.

It is also quite a messy approach and is often regretted it’s a thing at all.

The problems are loosely:

- the replacement works *exactly once*;
- letting extensions mess with core *definitions* can lead to very volatile results.

The problem with letting developers modify core files is often not *how* to allow this, but *how to make it unnecessary*. The latter is much more reasonable approach and basis for WP’s strong extensibility and success of its hooks API.